# How to combine data from two columns in excel to form a new column with combined data

Tags: excel

I have some data in two columns in an excel file, one column has 'Date' and other 'Time'. I want to combine in a 3rd column named as 'Timestamp' this data.

I find from search how to combine individual cells but not how to combine all date and make a new column with all data in new form.

Here is my data. 1st 2 columns 'Date', 'Time' I have and want to convert all the data from 1st two column into 3rd i.e. 'Timestamp'in given form,

```
   Date          Time          Timestamp 
   ----          ----          --------
15.06.2019.    18:10:01   15.06.2019 18:10:01
16.06.2019.    18:15:01.  15.06.2019 18:15:01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the strings can be parsed to dates and times, then you can use datevalue and timevalue.

```
=TIMEVALUE(B2)+DATEVALUE(A2)
```

If they are not parsable you need to change the order of the year month date in the date column

```
=TIMEVALUE(B2)+DATEVALUE(MID(A2,7,4)&"-"&MID(A2,4,2)&"-"&LEFT(A2,2))
```

This will make the date in a `YYYY-MM-DD` format which is parsable.

[image]
43632.76043 is the datetime stamp of the date which can be formated to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this simple approach, which also leaves the data close to its original format so you can still do calculations on it. In cell C2 us this formula:

```
=A2+B2
```

This assumes your date and time values are not strings, but actual date and time values.